# CREATE DATABASE stuck on SQL Server 2017 Failover Cluster

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017

We have Windows Server 2016 Failover Cluster, two nodes, both with SQL Server 2017 as failover cluster role too. SQL Server data are on a CIFS share, `\\172.20.2.10\\MSSQL_DATA`.

When I connect as `sa` SQL user, I can create new database. By SSMS or by `CREATE DATABASE` directly. It is done in a second.

When I connect as a domain user `Domain\SQLUser`, a database creation infinitly stuck. Without SQL permissions, I get `CREATE DATABASE permissions fail` immediately. With permission `CREATE ANY DATABASE`, or `dbcreator`, or `sysadmin`, SQL Server just hangs. The only way is Stop&Start SQL Server FC role.

During the hang, existing databases just works without problem. In SSMS I can browse existing database objects. But when I refresh a list of databases, SSMS stucks too.

How can I trace this problem? I tried SQL Server Profiler, with default options checked, I can see Batch task started but not completed.

Comment: Are you trying to add a new database to an availability group?

Comment: No, just other single database for another application.